# How to fix data frame Error: object not found message in R

Tags: r, object

I'm trying to create a new data frame, but keep getting an "Error: object 'Number' not found" message even though I just named the object. I'm analyzing data of insect visits to a flower, and I used a pipeline to group and then summarize the data by creating a new variable, Number, that counts the number of insects visits per taxa and puts it into a new column. I then named that new set of data counts. I am now trying to put it into a data frame, but at the first line (m <-etc.) I keep getting the error that the object Number isn't found. How do I fix this?

```
dcandata %>%
 group_by(`Flower.Species`, `Insect.Taxa`) %>%
 summarize(Number = n()) -> counts

m <- spread(counts[,2:2], Number, fill = 0)
rownames <- m$`Insect.Taxa`
m <- data.matrix(m[,2:2])
rownames(m) <- rownames
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `spread step should be either

```
 spread(counts, `Insect.Taxa`, Number, fill = 0)
```

or

```
spread(counts, Flower.Species, Number, fill = 0)
```